# Single&Double Column Dynamic Interface

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an interface that includes both single and double column buttons. You can see the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SZwQC/

As you can see in the fiddle, the actual width of the elements (with margins) is 130px; however, I had to give +2 additional pixels to be able to cover up the margins between double-column elements.

```
.single{
    width: 130px;
}

.double{
    width: 64px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

The result is just like how I want it to be, however, it is +2 pixels wider. Without the additional pixels, I could not find a way to do the 2 column items (by only adding the margin between the two).

I know this probably does not need a guru to solve, but I just could not find a perfect solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only add the `margin-right` to the first column:

```
<div class="double" style="margin-right:2px;">item</div>
<div class="double">item</div>
```

CSS:

```
.double{
    width: 64px;
}
```

**EDIT:** Here's how to do this by adding the styling in your CSS file, rather than hard-coded with the tag:

```
<div class="double1">item</div>
<div class="double2">item</div>
```

CSS:

```
.double1{
    width: 64px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.double2{
    width: 64px;
}
```

This works, or you can use an `id` on the first `div`, and style that `id` in your CSS to have `margin-right:2px;`. You could then keep both `div`s the same class (`double`) with `width:64px;` styling. This really is the best option *if* you're not going to be repeating this HTML code more than once.

Comment: than kyo ufor the reply, however, the items are dynamically generated and I'm trying to solve this via css-only

Comment: (when the items are added/removed your solution dies)

Comment: Thank you for the update, but as I mentioned, the content iss randomly generated. The "generic" squares sort of "slide" if any additional is added to the start/middle/end

Comment: @Zettam I'm not sure what you mean. I recommend changing your dynamic code to work properly using solutions I provided, or else provide me sample code of a situation that's causing the problem.